# Submenu, set position more left

Tags: html, css, menu

i've a small problem with my slide menu. The slide is fadin in from down to up. This also is working fine.

But now I want to set the position a bit more to the left side, so that i get a line with the main menu.

Maybe someone can help me. This is my sample...

```
This is my code...  [Menu][1]  https://jsfiddle.net/Tabes/eb52suo1/15/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution

```css
.flex-box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.navigation {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background-color: #111;
  width: 100%;
}


/* ******************************************************************************************* */


/* *****  Main Navigation - Main Level ******************************************************* */


/* ******************************************************************************************* */

.nav_main {
  background: transparent;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav_main ul:before,
.nav_main ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.nav_main ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}

.nav_main ul li:before,
.nav_main ul li:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline;
}

.nav_main ul li.icon:before,
.nav_main ul li.icon:after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 15px 0px 0px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.nav_main ul li.icon:before {
  background: url("../pic/icons/glyphicons-387-log-in.png") no-repeat top right;
  background-size: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.nav_main ul li.icon:after {
  background: url("../pic/icons/glyphicons-415-disk-save.png") no-repeat top left;
  background-size: 15px;
  float: right;
  margin: 2px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.nav_main ul li>img.before,
.nav_main ul li>img.after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 15px 0px 0px;
  width: 15px;
  height: auto;
}

.nav_main ul li>img.before {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.nav_main ul li>img.after {
  float: right;
  margin: 2px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.nav_main ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.nav_main ul li:hover {
  background: #444;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
}

.nav_main ul li {
  border-right: 1px solid #222;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
}

.nav_main ul li>a:hover {
  color: #fafafa;
}

.nav_main ul li>a {
  font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
  color: #999;
}

.nav_main ul li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
}


/* ******************************************************************************************* */


/* *****  Main Navigation - Level #1  ******************************************************** */


/* ******************************************************************************************* */

.nav_main ul ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #444;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 3px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 185px;
  min-height: 35px;
  width: auto;
}

.nav_main ul ul li:before,
.nav_main ul ul li:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline;
}

.nav_main ul ul li.icon:before,
.nav_main ul ul li.icon:after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 35px 0px 0px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.nav_main ul ul li.icon:before {
  background: url("../pic/icons/glyphicons-387-log-in.png") no-repeat top right;
  background-size: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin: 4px 35px 0px 0px;
}

.nav_main ul ul li.icon:after {
  background: url("../pic/icons/glyphicons-415-disk-save.png") no-repeat top left;
  background-size: 15px;
  float: right;
  margin: 4px 0px 0px 35px;
}

.nav_main ul ul li>img.before,
.nav_main ul ul li>img.after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 35px 0px 0px;
  width: 15px;
  height: auto;
}

.nav_main ul ul li>img.before {
  float: left;
  margin: 4px 35px 0px 0px;
}

.nav_main ul ul li>img.after {
  float: right;
  margin: 4px 0px 0px 35px;
}

.nav_main ul ul li:hover {
  background: #444;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
  background-color: #0186ba;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  min-width: 185px;
  min-height: 35px;
}

.nav_main ul ul li:first-child:hover {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
}

.nav_main ul ul li:last-child:hover {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
}

.nav_main ul ul li {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  min-width: 185px;
  min-height: 35px;
}

.nav_main ul ul li>a:hover {
  color: #fafafa;
}

.nav_main ul ul li>a {
  font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
  color: #999;
}

.nav_main ul ul li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main Navigation (Container for JavaScript Function)-->
<div id="Navigation" class="navigation">
  <!-- ### Main Navigation Link Liste ### -->
  <nav id="Nav_Main" class="nav_main">
    <ul class="flex-box">
      <li>
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
        <ul class="flex-box">
          <li>
            <a href="home/referenzen.html">Referenzen</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="home/downloads.html">Downloads</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="home/partner.html">Partner Programm</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="home/existenz.html">Existenzgr&uuml;nder</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <!-- <a href="home/philosophie.html">Philosophie</a> -->
            <a href="oopsy.html">Philosophie</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="hosting.html">Hosting</a>
        <ul class="flex-box">
          <li>
            <a href="hosting/webhosting.html">Web Hosting</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="hosting/cms/typo3.html">TYPO3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="hosting/cms/wordpress.html">WordPress</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="hosting/shop/mgento.html">Magento</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="hosting/shop/prestashop.html">PrestaShop</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="ajaxy" href="webdesign.html">WebDesign</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- ### Main Navigation Link Liste End ### -->
</div>
<!-- Main Navigation Container End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `flex-box` class you can add  a `margin-left: -35px;` and it will fix the position of the sub menu according to the snippet. You should mention though, that this might cause problems for the responsive part of your site.

Comment: mark the answer that fits for you ase solved so the question is closed.

Comment: how i can do it?

Comment: below the arrows displayed on the left top of every answer, you can vote up and mark if this answer solves your problem!